# Minimum number of items needed to cover all colors and tastes

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let's say I'm designing fictional fruits. The fruits have two attributes, color and taste. There are $n$ possible colors and $m$ possible tastes. Further, we're given an $n \times m$ feasibility matrix dictating which colors are compatible with which tastes. What is the minimum number of fruits I need to design such that all colors are covered by them and so are all tastes? What is a clever algorithm for solving this?

---

My attempt: the colors and tastes form a bi-partite graph. So, we imagine a source node, connected to all colors with capacities of $1$, then the colors are connected to tastes per the feasibility matrix (capacities $\infty$) and the tastes are connected to a sink node again with capacities $1$. We run a max flow. Some colors and tastes are covered; we eliminate them and repeat until all are covered. But this is probably not optimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the bipartite graph $G$ formed by the tastes and colors. Then what you're looking for is a minimum size edge set covering all the vertices of $G$; in other words, a [minimum edge cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_cover). It is not difficult to see that this can be done by finding a maximum matching and then arbitrarily picking one covering edge for each uncovered vertex (note that since the matching was maximal, these uncovered vertices are non-adjacent).

Your algorithm is indeed not optimal. For example, if $G$ is a complete bipartite graph plus one additional vertex of degree one, then it may only stop after selecting every edge of the graph.